# Unknown application "Identity API Scope Approval UI", is this standard for chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have noticed an unknown app in my mac applications list.
It's called "Identity API Scope Approval UI"
The app located in "Chrome apps" folder but i don't see it in Extensions page under "Chrome Apps" block.
I haven't noticed this app earlier
Is this chrome standard app, or i need to be worried ?

Chrome Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[screenshot of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Aqr.png)

Comment: This question doesn't concern software development or programming, so it's probably not on topic for Stack Overflow. (Maybe there is a different Stack Exchange site where it might belong; possibly not.) In any case, that appears to be a normal service that runs in Chrome, based on this bug report about its really ugly name: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=340428

Answer (score 5):

[image: operation[1]]

1. start the app，
2. right-click it from dock，choose options -- show in finder
3. remove it in finder

Answer (score 2):

I had the same and strangely enough it didn't show up in the Applications folder (GUI). Instead I just used Terminal, went to the Applications folder and typed:

```
ls (to check if I'm in the right folder and there was a folder "Chrome Apps.localized")
rm -R "Chrome Apps.localized"
```

So for some reason this app appeared to live inside the folder. Still not sure where it came from, but rather have it "out".